# Logback configuration when running in IDE

Tags: logging, configuration, logback, logback-classic

Are there any cool tricks to have a single `logback.xml` configuration that changes for PROD vs running in an IDE?

I want to use different appenders, patterns and log level based on whether I'm running in my IDE or if it's running in PROD in a jar.

I currently use 2 different files in `src/main/resources`: logback.xml (used in PROD/jar) and logback-dev.xml, used when running in my IDE. The part that is not ideal is that every developer has to configure their IDE launcher to include `-Dlogback.configurationFile=path/to/logback-dev.xml`. In other words, it doesn't work out of the box after a git clone. I'm also trying to avoid commiting IDE-specific launchers in my VCS

I saw the `<if>` construct but I'm not sure what conditionals I could use to detect the IDE. The `if` conditional seems to be very restrictive:

> The condition is a Java expression in which only context properties or system properties are accessible

I also tried using `logback-test.xml` in `src/test/resouces` but that only applies to unit tests and it's not copied by maven to the classpath when launching the app normally

If it's of any use, I'm using IntelliJ, maven and git

Answer (score 0):

You could launch your app from within the IDE using JUnit, this would cause `logback-test.xml` to be engaged. You could name this 'test' class something like `MyAppTool` i.e. with a suffix which would prevent Surefire from excuting it as a test. Or use a tag and a profile to exclude this 'test' case from your standard test suite invocations. For exampe:

```
public class MyAppTool {
  @Test
  public void runMyApp() {
    // invoke a 'main' class or however you run your app
  }
}
```

This is basically a way of "commiting IDE-specific launchers in my VCS" so if that's definitely not a runner then an alternative is to use the `<if>` construct but use a condition which is, by default, `true` for in-IDE invocations and `false` for PROD invocations. This would allow you to use a single `logback.xml` and the default behaviour would be as desired i.e. developers could launch your app from their IDE without having to create a customised launcher. The following example presumes that `logs.dir` is a JVM parameter which is always present when running your app in PROD mode:

```
<if condition='isNull("logs.dir")'>
  <then>
    <!-- in-IDE appenders -->
  </then>
  <else>
    <!-- standard appenders -->
  </else>
</if>
```

However you do this, you must provide some sort of *running-in-IDE / not-running-in-IDE* instruction so it's really a matter of which form of instruction best suits your usage.